# Custom ArrayAdapter not displaying results

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

This one has me quite stumped. I'm sure it is just something simple I am missing, but I cant seem to find out what...

When I run the program, it opens up the dialog box and displays the AutoCompleteTextView I have initialized. When I try to type something into it, nothing drops down or is displayed other than the text I type in. I have created a similar system in another part of my program with the same mechanics, but using a regular ArrayAdapter and it works fine so the interface is not the problem.

Here is where I initialize my custom ArrayList. I have been trying to use just strings to make it simpler.

```
final Dialog weaponDialog = new Dialog(BattleScreen.this);
        weaponDialog.setContentView(R.layout.weapon_selection_dialog);
        weaponDialog.setTitle("Add a Weapon");
        weaponDialog.setCancelable(true);

        String[] weaponStringArrayList = ConstantEquipmentHelper.getCondensedWeaponString();

        WeaponArrayAdapter weaponAdapter = new WeaponArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.weapon_list_item, weaponStringArrayList);

        weaponDialogAcTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.weaponSelectionAutoCompleteTxt);
        weaponDialogAddButton = (Button) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.weaponSelectionAddButton);
        weaponDialogWeaponInfo = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.weaponSelectionInformationTxt);
...
...
...
```

Here is my custom ArrayAdapter Class

```
public class WeaponArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    String[] objects;

    public WeaponArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.objects = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class WeaponItemHolder {
        TextView weaponName;
        TextView weaponCat;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final WeaponItemHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            //Sets up a new holder to temporaraly hold the listeners that will be assigned to the binded variables
            holder = new WeaponItemHolder();

            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weapon_list_item, null);

            //Find the IDs! Find them!!!!
            holder.weaponName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weaponListItemName);
            holder.weaponCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weaponListItemCategory);

            //"Sets the tag associated with this view. A tag can be used
            //to mark a view in its hierarchy and does not have to be unique within the hierarchy."
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (WeaponItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String spellName = objects[position];

        String[] weaponInfo = spellName.split("\\:");
        weaponInfo[1] = weaponInfo[1].trim();

        holder.weaponName.setText(weaponInfo[0]);
        holder.weaponCat.setText(weaponInfo[1]);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Additional Info: I have tried debugging it and it never reaches getView. This makes sense of course, as its not displaying anything.

Thanks,
-Andrew

EDIT: I have found out how to implement the above problem:

I used a SimpleAdapter with a custom layout.
However, now I can not select any of the items... onItemClick is not even called when I try to click it. It probably has to do with using the SimpleAdapter??

LINK: http://lemonbloggywog.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/customer-autocomplete-contacts-android/

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> weaponStringArrayList = ConstantEquipmentHelper.getCondensedWeaponString();


        //The adapter that recieves the layout type from android and the array creatd by the above function.
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, weaponStringArrayList, R.layout.weapon_list_item ,new String[] {"name", "category"}, new int[] { R.id.weaponListItemName, R.id.weaponListItemCategory});

        //Find the view blah blah blah...
        weaponDialogAcTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.weaponSelectionAutoCompleteTxt);
        weaponDialogAddButton = (Button) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.weaponSelectionAddButton);
        weaponDialogWeaponInfo = (TextView) weaponDialog.findViewById(R.id.weaponSelectionInformationTxt);

        //Set that adapter!
        weaponDialogAcTextView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement getCount() and set the count of your data, i.e. objects.length.

You also have to set the adapter to the view using the method setAdapter().

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added that and it is still behaving the same. Debug did not get to getCount().

Comment: I had implemented that below where the ellipsis are. My apologies for not including it.I may know the problem... It appears I may need to implement a Filter to populate the drop-down...

Comment: I found a way to do what I wanted. See Additional edited code above.